# What do square brackets do in Perl?

Tags: perl, literals

I'm confused with the usage of square bracketed comma delimited elements in perl:

```
[short($file), -s $file];
```

Can somebody tell me what does this code mean?

Comment: [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`[]` creates an array reference.

`[ $scalar, $scalar ]` creates an array reference with two items in it.

`short($file)` calls a subroutine and returns something (probably a scalar or a list of scalars)

`-s $file` gives you the size of the file (as a scalar).

`[short($file), -s $file]` gives you an array ref containing the above two things.

Answer (score 9):

It creates a reference to an array with two items, the result of a function call to `short($file)` and the size of the `$file`.

Comment: Also see the perlref manual page and the perlreftut manual page.

Comment: I thought this was an array. I've got to read this. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html thanks.